# Grammar error when flagging

Tags: bug, flags, grammatical-correction

I see that recently flag descriptions were changed, from "too broad" to "Needs more focus"

But as you see, header wasn't changed to fit:
[image]

Now we have this strange:

> **This question doesn't belong here because it is** Needs details or clarity

and

> **This question doesn't belong here because it is** Needs more focus

I suggest removing '**is**' from header, and add it at the beginning of other flags, so "Is a duplicate of...", "Is off-topic because..." and "Is opinion-based".

Comment: You should create an answer post here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow to report that issue (but check first if it hasn't been reported yet)